# Media player error:- when i decrease seek bar then volume is decreasing but on progress increase it is not increase volume in real state

Tags: android, media-player, android-audiomanager

i have a problem in my media player AudioManager. When i decrease volume of sound through seekbar i will decrease but when i do progress increase it is not increase sound volume in same state.. please help me to sort out my problem.. 
thanks in Advance...

```
audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
int curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

volume2 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.volbar2);
volume1 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.volbar);

volume1.setMax(maxVolume);
volume2.setMax(maxVolume);
volume1.setProgress(curVolume);
volume2.setProgress(curVolume);

volume1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

  }
  @Override
  public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

  }
  @Override
  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean arg2) {       
    if(seekBar.equals(volume1)){
      mediaPlayer.setVolume((progress/100.0f),(progress/100.0f));
    }
  }
});

volume2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

  public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(seekBar.equals(volume2)){ 
      mediaPlayer2.setVolume((progress/100.0f),(progress/100.0f));
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Check after remove if condition from onProgressChanged . No need to check condition because you write different onProgresschanged for both seekbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code works 
Enjoy

```
     audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(this.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    seekBar.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));



    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            audioManager.setStreamVolume(audioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);

        }
    });
```